# How to get transaction ID in braintree sale

Tags: python, braintree

Is there a way to get the Transaction ID of a sale that I just made. Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> sale=braintree.Transaction.sale({'amount': '0.05', 'customer_id': '17419473'})
>>> sale.transaction
<Transaction {amount: Decimal('0.05'), credit_card: {u'bin': u'411111', u'expiration_month': u'12', u'unique_number_identifier': u'a05f827ae3578b49d685ee2200dfaa97', u'prepaid': u'Unknown', u'expiration_year': u'2024', u'durbin_regulated': u'Unknown', u'payroll': u'Unknown', u'debit': u'Unknown', u'commercial': u'Unknown', u'issuing_bank': u'Unknown', u'last_4': u'1111', u'card_type': u'Visa', u'cardholder_name': None, u'token': u'9k5jxr', u'customer_location': u'US', u'image_url': u'https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox', u'country_of_issuance': u'Unknown', u'healthcare': u'Unknown', u'venmo_sdk': False, u'product_id': u'Unknown'}} at 4510688208>
```

Unfortunately, I don't see the `TransactionID` in the above output. Actually, I only see the `amount` and `credit_card` info. How would I get TransactionID from the sale? My use case is that after a user pays for something, I want to store that transaction ID for the purchase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're currently looking at the string representation of the object, not all attributes that the `Transaction` object has. Try `dir(sale.transaction)` to see all the attributes that the object has.

You're most likely looking for the `sale.transaction.id` or `sale.transaction.order_id` attribute (see [docs](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/python/transactions/details)), depending on whether you want the record/object's identifier or the order identifier from the customer's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

`sale.transaction.id` should give you the transaction ID.